# Getting refresh_token as null on re-authenticating Gmail API for sending email using Oauth

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, gmail-api

I am using Scribe for oauth to get access_token and refresh_token for the auth_code. It worked well for the first authentication.
When I disabled the credentials in my application, the tokens are still existing with the Gmail connected apps for my application. 
When I re-enable the oauth, I am getting only valid new access_token for the new auth_code. But the refresh_token is null. 
I tried to replicate the same with [oauthplayground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/), there I could see valid refresh and access tokens, while playground tokens still existed in the google connected apps.

here is the code I implemented with scribe-1.3.0 API

```
    OAuthRequest oAuthRequest = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");

    oAuthRequest.addBodyParameter("client_id", SMTP_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID);
    oAuthRequest.addBodyParameter("client_secret", SMTP_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET);

    oAuthRequest.addBodyParameter("scope", scope);
    oAuthRequest.addBodyParameter("redirect_uri", GoogleApi.getRedirectURL());

    oAuthRequest.addBodyParameter("code", authCode);
    oAuthRequest.addBodyParameter("grant_type", "authorization_code");

    Response response = oAuthRequest.send();
```

Here is the similar code tried with googleapi-client-1.20, the result is still same.

```
        GoogleTokenResponse tokenResponse = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(
                new NetHttpTransport(), 
                new JacksonFactory(), 
                SMTP_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID, SMTP_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET, 
                authCode, 
                GoogleApi.getRedirectURL())
                    .execute();

        Credential gcredential = new GoogleCredential
                .Builder()
                .setTransport(new NetHttpTransport.Builder().build())
                .setJsonFactory(new JacksonFactory())
                .setClientSecrets(SMTP_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID, SMTP_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET)
                .build()
                .setFromTokenResponse(tokenResponse);

        gcredential.refreshToken();

        System.out.println(gcredential.getRefreshToken());
```

Can anyone help me where I am going wrong?
Thanks for your time in looking at this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When re-authenticating you need to set these parameters
`access_type=offline` and `approval_prompt=force`
then you will recieve `refresh_token`

Below is an example URL
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=CLIENT_ID&scope=SCOPE&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URL&response_type=code&access_type=offline&approval_prompt=force

Comment: SUPER. IT WORKED.